# Android word wrap without breaking or ellipsizing

Tags: android

I want to display part of a long text string in a single line TextView without breaking words or ellipsizing.

For example,

> This is my very long text string, which is extremely long.

I want this to show up in a single-line TextView as

> This is my very long text

**NOT**

> This is my very long text strin

OR

> This is my very long text st...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringTokenizer` with a space separation to iterate throw your words. Use this code to check the current string could fit in the TextView:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect(); 
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
int textWidth = bounds.getWidth();
```